# Finding the optimal set of pairwise alignments from a similarity matrix, with some wrinkles, in Python

Tags: python, alignment, sequences

I am trying to find the best alignment of two sequences from a similarity matrix. Higher values indicate better alignments.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([
[0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
[3,10,0,0,0,9,0,0],
[3,0,10,0,0,0,1,0],
[3,0,0,9,0,0,0,0],
[3,0,0,0,0,0,0,10],
])
```

Each row/column must be aligned to exactly one column/row, except for row 0 and column 0, which may be used in 0 or more alignments.

That is, the best alignment for these sequences is:

```
(0,0)
(1,1)
(2,2)
(3,3)
(0,4)
(0,5)
(0,6)
(4,7)
```

`(1,5)` is not an aligned pair, because `(1,1)` is a better alignment, and rows and columns > 0 can only participate in one alignment.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am changing the problem slightly. Now each column must be aligned to exactly one row, and each row must be aligned to exactly one column. To make the matrix square, I am adding rows/columns that are equivalent to row/column 0, which previously could participate in multiple alignments. With a square matrix and a requirement that each row/column participate in only one alignment, the problem can be treated as an instance of the stable marriage problem.

Comment: You should be able to edit your problem directly and not have to add your changes as an answer (which they strictly speaking aren't).  :-)